# ElasticSearch is unable to recognize Context-Type header with encoding defined

Tags: elasticsearch, httprequest, content-type, ndjson, elasticsearch-bulk

I've spent some time trying to fix the elastic search bulk upload warning:

> Content type detection for rest requests is deprecated. Specify the content type using the [Content-Type] header

My request is below:

```
POST http://elasticserver/_bulk HTTP/1.1
Authorization: xxx
Content-Type: application/x-ndjson; charset=utf-8
Host: elasticserver
Content-Length: 8559

... new line delimited json content ...
```

And my valid response with 200 status is below:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Warning: 299 Elasticsearch-5.5.1-19c13d0 "Content type detection for rest requests is deprecated. Specify the content type using the [Content-Type] header." "Mon, 14 Aug 2017 00:46:21 GMT"
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 4183

{"took":5538,"errors":false,...}
```

By experimenting I discovered that the issue is in content type charset definition `Content-Type: application/x-ndjson; charset=utf-8` and if I change it to `Content-Type: application/x-ndjson` I get no warning.

Is it an elastic search issue or I'm forming the request incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

The [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) explicitly states that

> When sending requests to this endpoint the Content-Type header should be set to application/x-ndjson.

The [`RestController` source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/4b18800df9a640ce9d8275066494936ffe54ede0/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/rest/RestController.java#L277-L281) also shows that they are ignoring the charset:

```
final String lowercaseMediaType = restRequest.header("Content-Type").toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
// we also support newline delimited JSON: http://specs.okfnlabs.org/ndjson/
if (lowercaseMediaType.equals("application/x-ndjson")) {
    restRequest.setXContentType(XContentType.JSON);
    return true;
}
```